# Can FSMs be Timed and Recursive?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

I am reading a textbook *Circuit Design with VHDL, 3rd Edition* by Volnei Pedroni. There, he claims that there exist 3 categories of finite-state machines - namely, regular, timed (where the output depends on the time as well as on the input), and recursive (where the output also depends ont he previous outputs):
[image: Three categories of FSMs, according to Volnei Pedroni]

So here's the question: to those two other FSM categories fall under the strict mathematical definition of an FSM? Is it even valid to call them finite-state machines?

UPD: Is the circuit below (which has an "auxiliary register" in addition to the state register) still an FSM?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timed and recursive state machines are much more common than untimed state machines, at least among state machines that are deliberately designed as state machines rather than circuits designed by some other process that happen to also have the features of state machines. What makes you think these types aren't normally considered "state machines"?

Within the field of digital logic, if a circuit doesn't have recursion (aka feedback) and doesn't depend on time, then we usually call it "combinatorial logic" and consider it as **not** a state machine.

Comment: Well, I assumed that the formal definition of a state machine implies that the only memory it has comes from the state register. However, a recursive state machine requires another register in addition to that (the one that would store the recurrent output).

Comment: It doesn't require any added registers if it only remembers one past state (i.e. the current state contributes to determining the next state). And if it does depend on further past states, you can trivially redefine what is your state register to include the "added" register and you're back to only depending on one past state. Also, the register itself depends on recursion for its operation.

Comment: by definition, a recursive state machine remembers the previous output and increments/decrements it in accordance with the inputs and current state - so we have to use some other memory in addition to the state register than only remembers the state

Comment: @Mr_Tusk, the output doesn't have to depend on all the bits in the state register. It can depend on only some of them. And other bits in the state register can be used to keep track of the previous state of some other bits in the state register. In any case, if the definition of a "recursive state machine" is more nuanced, then you should provide the whole definition in your question post.

Comment: thank you, I get what you mean now. I updated the question a little bit to clarify what I meant.

Comment: @Mr_Tusk, looking at your edit, you could still just consider the "aux. reg." to be part of the state vector, and you're back to the normal definitions of a state machine.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here is a state machine [with multiple delays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138152/vhdl-state-machine-with-several-delays-best-approach/31139055#31139055)

Here is one that is [literally recursive](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/113329/return-from-idle-state/113337#113337) : it can push "state" to "saved_state", do something else, and return to "saved_state".

And a hierarchical state machine, [with outer and inner states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612604/substatemachine/32620346#32620346), which can be an alternative to the literally recursive one above.